# Foreach messes up the values. PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have this function that what it does is add cities.

The code works more or less well but when doing the foreach it messes up the values.

This is the code

```json
    public function updateciudadpreciosdelivery(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->except(['_token', 'restaurant_id']);
        $i = 0;
        $str = '{';
        foreach ($data as $day => $times) {
            $str .= '"' . $day . '":[';
            if ($times) {
                foreach ($times as $key => $time) {
                    if ($key % 3 == 0) {
                        $t1 = $time;
                        $str .= '{"open" :' . '"' . $time . '"';
                    }
                    elseif ($key % 2 == 0) {
                        $t3 = $time;
                        $str .= '"cod" :' . '"' . $time . '"}';
                    }
                    else {
                        $t2 = $time;
                        $str .= '"close" :' . '"' . $time . '"';
                    }
                    //check if last, if last then dont add comma,
                    if (count($times) != $key + 1) {
                        $str .= ',';
                    }
                }
                //dd($t3);
            } else {
                $str .= '}]';
            }
            if ($i != count($data) - 1) {
                $str .= '],';
            } else {
                $str .= ']';
            }
            $i++;
        }
        $str .= '}';
        dd($str);
        // Fetches The Restaurant
        $restaurant = Restaurant::where('id', $request->restaurant_id)->first();
        // Enters The Data
        if ($str == "{}") {
                $restaurant->deliveryciudadprecios = null;
        }
        else {
        $restaurant->deliveryciudadprecios = $str;          
        }
        $restaurant->delivery_charge_type = 'XCIUDAD';
        // Saves the Data to Database
        $restaurant->save();
        return redirect()->back()->with(['success' => 'Las ciudades se guardaron correctamente']);      
    }
```

In the first foreach I get this string with 2 cities added.

1er foreach
`"{"ciudad":[{"open" :"Piura","close" :"15","cod" :"true"},`

2do foreach
`{"open" :"Lima","cod" :"15"},"close" :"true"]}"`

Foreach complete wrong:

`{"ciudad":[{"open" :"Piura","close" :"15","cod" :"true"},{"open" :"Lima","cod" :"15"},"close" :"true"]}`

As should be the correct foreach

`{"ciudad":[{"open" :"Piura","close" :"15","cod" :"true"},{"open" :"Lima","close" :"15","cod" :"true"}]}`

**As you can see, the order of the cod and close keys changes, why does this happen?**

Try to be as clear as possible. If this is poorly written, please just notify us to correct it, please do not report.

My variable $data

```json
array:1 [▼
  "ciudad" => array:6 [▼
    0 => "Piura"
    1 => "10"
    2 => "true"
    3 => "Lima"
    4 => "20"
    5 => "true"
  ]
]
```

Comment: Don't use string operations to create JSON. Put the data in arrays, and use `json_encode()`.

Comment: That will ensure that the JSON is constructed properly, and it will fix this problem.

Comment: The problem here is that you only do `$str .= '}]';` when `$times` is empty. It should be done all the time.

Comment: @Barmar How could I fix it please?

Comment: @Barmar json_encode() is not an option because the structure of the site is this way when adding new cities. :(

Answer (score 1):

Don't create the string using concatenation. Create an array and then convert it to a string with `json_encode()`.

```
public function updateciudadpreciosdelivery(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->except(['_token', 'restaurant_id']);
    $i = 0;
    $result = [];
    foreach ($data as $day => $times) {
        $day_result = [];
        foreach ($times as $key => $time) {
            if ($key % 3 == 0) {
                $day_result["open"] = $time;
            }
            elseif ($key % 2 == 0) {
                $day_result["cod"] = $time;
            }
            else {
                $day_result["close"] = $time;
            }
        }
        $result[$day][] = $day_result;
    }
    // Fetches The Restaurant
    $restaurant = Restaurant::where('id', $request->restaurant_id)->first();
    // Enters The Data
    if (empty($result)) {
        $restaurant->deliveryciudadprecios = null;
    }
    else {
        $restaurant->deliveryciudadprecios = json_encode($result);
    }
    $restaurant->delivery_charge_type = 'XCIUDAD';
    // Saves the Data to Database
    $restaurant->save();
    return redirect()->back()->with(['success' => 'Las ciudades se guardaron correctamente']);      
}
```

Comment: I thank you very much but when trying to retrieve the values it does not work.

I'm trying to see it on the blade with this:


```json

'deliverycityprices' => json_decode($restaurant->deliverycityprices),
```

Comment: I solved it by changing this part
```$result[$day] = [$day_result];```

The problem now is that it only takes the new value and not the old values. :(

Comment: Dear @Barmar the code works, however it only takes the last array and not all the previous ones, there is some way to take all the data, for example this variable $data:

```json

array:1 [▼
  "ciudad" => array:6 [▼
    0 => "Piura"
    1 => "10"
    2 => "true"
    3 => "Lima"
    4 => "20"
    5 => "true"
  ]
]
```

Comment: I Edit the original post with the $data variable to make it easier to see.

Comment: I fixed it to `$result[$day][] = $day_result;` to make an array of all the day results.

Comment: Copy the code as you put it but still take the last value and not all. :(

Comment: This is an example of how it should look taking all the values that are sent through the post

`{"ciudad":[{"open" :"Piura","close" :"10","cod" :"0"},{"open" :"Lima","close" :"20","cod" :"0"},{"open" :"Pisco","close" :"30","cod" :"0"},{"open" :"Arequipa","close" :"40","cod" :"0"},{"open" :"Loreto","close" :"50","cod" :"0"}]}`

Comment: And this would be the values

`array:1 [▼
  "ciudad" => array:15 [▼
    0 => "Piura"
    1 => "10"
    2 => "0"
    3 => "Lima"
    4 => "20"
    5 => "0"
    6 => "Pisco"
    7 => "30"
    8 => "0"
    9 => "Arequipa"
    10 => "40"
    11 => "0"
    12 => "Loreto"
    13 => "50"
    14 => "0"
  ]
]`

Comment: Currently your code only takes the last value :(

Comment: Please add the output of `var_export($data);` to the question so I can test with your data.